# How do I configure apache to work with a virtual network adapter

Tags: apache-2.2

I have set up a virtual network adapter with a secondary IP address on my server (as per here: http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/create-virtual-network-adapters-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/)

I want apache, mysql and php to work with this secondary IP address. So if I SSH onto my server (using the primary ip address, not the virtual one), and just run something like

sudo apt-get install apache2

This installs apache, but I want it to be installed for the secondary IP address. Will apache automatically work for the secondary IP address too? If not, how do I install it so it will work?

Comment: What, exactly, is a virtual network drive? That's not a term that has any real meaning.

Comment: it will work, you may need to update your LISTEN directives http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is the [listen](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.html) directive.

```
listen ip.address.of.eth0-1:port
```

e.g.

```
listen 192.168.1.1:80
```

Comment: Or just `Listen 80` if listening on all interfaces is acceptable.

Comment: @ShaneMadden: oh absolutely but the OP witters on about primary and secondary addresses so I ran with it ;) How's it going anyway ?

Comment: Heh, fair enough!  Not too bad, yourself?

Answer (score 1):

assuming real ip is aa and virtual ip is bb, then by default with no config changes, both ips will serve the same content, as apache accepts incoming http requests on all interfaces.
 however using virtual-host will allow you to serve specific content for ip aa and another different content for ip bb.